# How to make farmer villagers plant other plants (mine are only planting beetroot)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had a farm with a lot of variety (around 10 farmers locked on the farm, near beds and composters), but it soon became a beetroot infested farm. I think my villagers have an inventory full of beet seeds..is there a way to manage?

Id rather have them planting a bit of everything. But if not possible, Id prefer it to be weath.

Comment: It might work to just remove the beetroot and plant other crops, maybe repeating that a few times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Mixed" farm doesn't work as sooner or later one crop dominates it. Villagers have up to 8 stacks of items on them, so they may hold  a bunch of beetroot seeds. Rip the plants out before they mature, so the villagers deplete their beetroot seed supply, then either plant a bunch of wheat seeds or throw them at the villagers (or both). Once you have majority of the farm growing wheat, the remaining beetroots should gradually get phased out.